# Unable to invoke ck-editor textarea (Uncaught TypeError: $(...).ckeditor is not a function)

Tags: jquery, laravel, ckeditor

I'm using Laravel 5.7 with a package called [laravel-ckeditor](https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-ckeditor) and I cannot invoke the ck-editor textarea.

I'm including the package and script into my view like so (this loads them at the bottom of my file, just above the `</body>` tag):

```
@section('js')
  <script src="{{asset('js/render_select2.js')}}" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="/vendor/unisharp/laravel-ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
  <script src="{{asset('js/render_ckeditor.js')}}" charset="utf-8"></script>
@endsection
```

The file `ckeditor.js` is being loaded in correctly, I can open it when viewing the page source.

I've even added the application service provider to my `app.php` file and published the assets.

jQuery is included **before** this. jQuery works since I can use it in another script without any issues. The file `render_ckeditor.js` contains this line:

```
$('.ck-textarea').ckeditor();
```

This is the textarea:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      {{Form::label('description', 'Product description')}}
      {{Form::textarea('description', '', ['id' => 'ck-textarea', 'class' => 'form-control ck-textarea', 'style' => 'resize: vertical', 'placeholder' => 'Product description'])}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried to invoke it by using the ID instead of the class, changing my `render_ckeditor.js` file to this:

```
$('#ck-textarea').ckeditor();
```

Using the ID or class both resulted in this error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).ckeditor is not a function at render_ckeditor.js:1

What am I missing here?

Comment: did you include **adapters/jquery.js**?

Comment: No! I just tried it and it works now, I must admit, I __totally__ overlooked the additional include. Add it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that I have to include the jQuery adapter (duhh..), totally overlooked the additional include.

Adding this solved it:

```
<script src="/vendor/unisharp/laravel-ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js"></script>
```